# HTTP server fuzzer

Tags: gratis, linux, http

I am in the situation where I need to test the HTTP header parsing of a particular custom HTTP server.

However, that server is behind a load balancer that check the first line of the header contains `.git/info/refs?service=git-`. If it doesn’t, the request isn’t forwarded, but if it does, then everything after the first line is send without modifications *(the response channel goes farther because it acts as a raw tcp stream proxy at the load balancer)*.

I saw American Fuzzing Loop, but I have no idea on how to use it for that purpose.

Comment: Which OS? What is your budget? What is the impact of the load balancer to the software you request?

Comment: @Thomas : updated tags.